# Раскодировать ответ от сервера в UTF8

Tags: python

Есть текст, который сервер отвечает на запрос, но он закодирован, и браузером раскодируется в человеческий UTF-8. Хочу раскодировать его Python-скриптом, есть какие либо модули, определяющие кодировку и умеющие раскодировать? Текст от сервера приходит примерно такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `chardet` может выявлять кодировку и соответственно кодировать/декодировать

Comment: ungzip и еще 9 символов

Comment: @Barton Кодировку определил, но в доках chardet что то не нахожу команды расшифровки в UTF-8